# Windows 10 fonts look white shaded on Full HD TV

Tags: windows-10, colors, external-display, hdtv, contrast

I am just going to put two pictures here and I hope one of you guys tells me how to get rid of the white area behind the letters? I have tried contrast, brightness, etc. nothing worked so far.

[image: Philips TV Display]

[image: ASUS Laptop Display]

Comment: Your TV has enhancements in place that do this. This is a setting on your TV. You can try setting your TV in game mode or find what setting it is and disable it.

Comment: Usually this is some kind of "sharpening" setting.

Comment: @Mokubai I just found it as soon as LPChip suggested. However, it doesn't seem enough. Still, the white area behind the letters but not much

Comment: Also check your graphics card settings, sometimes there are additional sharpening settings in there that are applied before the signal goes to your display.

Comment: @Mokubai you mean Intel Graphics application?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is not a problem of Windows but the TV settings.

Adjust the TV settings. Turn off all image enhancement features. Refer to TV manual what features there are, what they do and how to adjust them.